# You've added another git repository inside your current repository

Tags: git

I got this warning because I made `git add folder` with existing `folder/.git`. The warning says that cloned repo will not know how to obtain the subrepo. How can it be possible, since the URL is written inside `folder/.git/config` ?

Comment: If ```folder``` already is itself a clone of a repository, perhaps you need to use https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `git submodule` if you want to include another git folder into an existing git repo.

To do so:

```
$ git submodule init
```

A much better way to do it is by creating two separate git repo and use git submodule.

[More about Git Submodule is here.](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

Comment: I know but I want to know the reasoning. Why can't we just do `git add`?

Comment: I believe it's the design architecture of how `git` application is designed to work. Technically, your local cloned repo is communicating with the server-side repo (at github) with the help of `.git` folder  which resides inside your folder. It contains SHA1 (hash files). Now that you have multiple `.git` thus multiple SHA1 information, git software is confused as to which one to choose.